# Checking for the existing cookies doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I would like to trigger click on my video to show when page has specific cookie.
but by any reason it doesn't work for me, i'm newbie in jQuery and will appreciate your help.

Here is my code ( for see the full code please loo at the working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vPELX/91/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery('.video-thumb').click(function() {

            var vidId = $(this).attr('id');
            var vidBg = $(this).attr('data-bg');
            $('#container').html('<iframe data-color="'+vidBg+'" id="player_'+vidId+'" width="420" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vidId + '?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
            });

        });
    if (getCookie('username') && getCookie('temp')) {
            $( ".initial" ).click();
            aler('Cookies are set');
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you trying to do, but in your fiddle you are only placing the cookie 'username' and you never set the cookie 'temp', so this will not execute because 'temp' cookie does not exists:

```
if (getCookie('username') && getCookie('temp')) {
    $( ".initial" ).click();
    alert('Cookies are set');
}
```

If you're looking for just one of the cookies you should use

```
if (getCookie('username') || getCookie('temp')) {
    $( ".initial" ).click();
    alert('Cookies are set');
}
```

Comment: I'd like to check if one of those cookies exist then do something, so i changed the && to || and worked for me but i'm not sure why that happened, it supposed to be worked with &&

Comment: No, the AND Operator `&&` will be true if both cookies exists the OR Operator `||` will be true if only one of the cookie exists. You can check on [logical operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: ah cool, so let's edit your answer so i can mark it as answered.